# What is a cantrip and what page are they on?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, terminology

I'm making a bard and it says I have 2 cantrips and 4 spells, and I just have no idea where they are and how to establish them at all.

Comment: I'm assuming since you reference the "page" on which cantrips could be found, that you've got the Player's Handbook. If you're working from some other reference please indicate so, and I'll adjust pointers accordingly.

Comment: Lastly (and in reverse order of importance), welcome to the site! When you get a chance go ahead and take the [tour]. I fear you may get some downvotes as other users think this is a question asking someone to read the book to you. I, generally, am sympathetic: D&D is a great game that somehow, through forty years, has never really found a way to explain itself to newcomers!

Answer (score 18):

### Cantrips are Zeroth-level spells

As such you can cast them as often as you'd like. ("Leveled" spells cost spell slots, which are a finite resource.) You can find more about the details of spell levels on pp.201-202, "Spellcasting."

### A Bard gets cantrips...

from the "bard list" starting on p.207. The individual spells are then detailed in alphabetical order from pp.211-289.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the PhB in the spells chapter (ch 11) it will list all the spells (including cantrips) that your class can learn. Cantrips are just spells you can cast at will and not have to worry about spell slots